# onClick event problems with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, fullcalendar

I am having sporadic issues with fullCalendar and the click hook in Internet Explorer 9 (this is not an issue in FireFox, Chrome or Opera it seems).

The function I have attached to the click hook when a user clicks an event will only trigger if I first launch the developer console in Internet Explorer and refresh the page. I can then close the console again and use  the page as normal, but if I return 24 hours later, I will have to repeat this step to be able to use the functionality again.

My Internet Explorer settings appear fine, as this is not a problem with just this one machine, but also with 5 other machines I have tested this on.

Comment: This sounds weird, could you provide a test case on http://jsfiddle.net/ so it can be reproduced perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

sounds like there is a `console.log()` included but without any code provided we can only take a guess.

Comment: Yes, sounds like it. You can try adding ``console.log = console.log || function(){}`` and see if it prevents the error from happening.

Comment: Hmmm, I just made my jQuery dialog appear before making an ajax call, and now everythign seems to work on every attempt, quite peculiar.